# magento multi select category

Tags: ajax, magento

how to multi select category and filter product based on selected category in magento
I have search for extension but all are paid extension is there any free extension to perform multi select category layer navigation in magento

Answer (score 1):

There are many free extensions available

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/creative-layered-navigation-pro.html

Comment: I doesn'tmean that consider category (fruit vegetable ,furniture)if I select the checkbox of fruit and vegetable category it should filter result of product only on that particular category if I remove any checked mark of any category product on that category should get remove from filter result

Comment: I need help immediately if any body have any idea kindly suggest me as soon as possible\

Comment: i dont know what you didnt understand but the filters works like what you asked 

check the below demo 

http://instore.gorillagroup.com/demo/apparel#cat=36%2C37&dir=asc&order=position

Comment: ya you are right but it is not displaying in my front end as well as back end

Comment: your demo link is working perfectly but given extension is not displaying I am waiting for your reply

Comment: Give me a guidance as soon as possible because I am trying to fix this issue more than one week